# Word meaning "feather-like"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for feather-like. **Pinnated** doesn't fit, nor fern-like or anything I have thought of. I'd love something to use as in *phocine* for *seal-like*.

Answer (score 5):

How about "[plumose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plumose?show=0&t=1341120313)"?

It has the same meaning as "[feathery](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feathery)."

Answer (score 4):

**Pennaceous** is [one word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pennaceous) common in ornithology for *feather-like*. You could also use these words derived from **plume**. (See [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plumose).)

- **plumose**
- **plumate**
- **plumous**

One point to note is the latter set of words could be used both for *feather-like* and *feathery*, so the usage is inferred from the context. Going by the OED, only **plumose** stands for *feather-like*; the rest are for *having feathers* or *feathery*.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to *pinnated* is *pennate*, used to refer to the feather-like strands of the bicep, for instance.